# Subtracting properties in a list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following: (C# code, VS2013)

```
class DailyTemp
{
    public int Day;
    public int LowTemp;
    public int HighTemp;
}

List<DailyTemp> dailyTemps = new List<DailyTemp>();
//I fill this list with DailyTemp objects
```

My questions is, how do I write a lambda expression to go through my list and return the day that has the smallest difference between high and low temps? Thank you for your time.

Comment: whoever down voted should comment why

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
return dailyTemps.OrderBy(dt => dt.HighTemp - dt.LowTemp).Select(dt => dt.Day).First();
```

As noted by @Colin DeClue, it's more efficient to call `Select` before `First` so that we're retrieving the minimum needed information from the data source (which can matter on larger data sets coming from a DB).

Comment: Any reason you did the .Select before the .First instead of doing .First().Day ?

Comment: @Kazmatron: `.First` evaluates the expression, `.Select` doesn't. So if `dailyTemps` is coming from a database, it will be more efficient to call `Select` first.

Comment: @ColinDeClue That's very useful to know. Hopefully Ryan puts that in his post.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do an approach with a single pass over the sequence and using built-in methods, you can leverage `Enumerable.Aggregate` and keep the argument with the lowest temperature difference, discarding the other.

```
Func<DailyTemp, int> tempDiff = x => x.HighTemp - x.LowTemp;    
var day = dailyTemps.Aggregate((a, b) => tempDiff(a) < tempDiff(b) ? a : b);
```

Otherwise, MoreLinq's `MinBy` might read simpler (externally available API), as well as the `OrderBy` method available within the BCL (that requires sorting), each approach being highlighted in other visible answers.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the [MinBy method of MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs?r=2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c) (argument validation removed below) to get the min value of a collection based on the value of a selector:

```
public static TSource MinBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> selector)
{
    return source.MinBy(selector, Comparer<TKey>.Default);
}
public static TSource MinBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> selector, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> sourceIterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!sourceIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence was empty");
        }
        TSource min = sourceIterator.Current;
        TKey minKey = selector(min);
        while (sourceIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            TSource candidate = sourceIterator.Current;
            TKey candidateProjected = selector(candidate);
            if (comparer.Compare(candidateProjected, minKey) < 0)
            {
                min = candidate;
                minKey = candidateProjected;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

This lets us write:

```
var day = dailyTemps.MinBy(dt => dt.HighTemp - dt.LowTemp);
```

Comment: +1, but what if there are several elements in the sequence with the same minimum? Your implementation will return just the first such element.

Comment: @stakx The asker's question seems to indicate (`return the day`) that they're only ever looking for a single item.

Comment: @furkle: Correct. If I may make a suggestion, include the word(s) `First` in your operator's name. That will make it easy for the consumer to figure out what exactly it does, thanks to the name similarity to the default operators. And it might even lead the consumer to question themselves whether there can only be one element, or whether there might in fact be several.